# Difference in the declaration beyween two syntaxes

Tags: arrays, declaration

Ref : [Cannot reference "X" before supertype constructor has been called, where x is a final variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963775/cannot-reference-x-before-supertype-constructor-has-been-called-where-x-is-a)

```
class ArrayFunctions {

    //public Integer[] arrayTemplate;

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayFunctions(int k){
            Integer[] arrayTemplate = new Integer[k] ;
        }
        .
        .
        .
    public class ArrayFunctionsImplementation{

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ArrayFunctions newArray  = new ArrayFunctions(5);
            newArray.getIntegers(newArray.arrayTemplate);
            newArray.printIntegers(newArray.arrayTemplate);
            newArray.sortArray(newArray.arrayTemplate);
            newArray.printIntegers(newArray.arrayTemplate);

        }

    }
}
```

If I use the declaration //public Integer[] arrayTemplate; that is currently commented out , I am able to access the variable "arrayTemplate" in the public class.

But if I declare the variable by calling the constructor as per the code below, I am unable to access it anywhere. If I understand correctly, both the ways declare the variable and by the time I am trying to access it , the object is already created.

PS : I am using Integer class just for experimentation instead of using plain int

Cheers

Comment: you should add the java tag to this

Answer (score 0):

Your current code declares a variable of the `ArrayFunctions` constructor and so, that variable is only accessible in your constructor.

Your commented code, declares a member of the `ArrayFunctions` class, which then can be accessed anywhere from the class (or elsewhere since you made it `public`).

Comment: Thanks. If I get you correctly, are you saying that the variable has only constructor scope, because that is a method after all.

Comment: yeah, the constructor is a method. and any variable declared in a method, is limited to this method.

Comment: Thanks !. I "knew" this but I know now.

Comment: you're welcome, that said, please update your tags to include "java", and select an answer to mark this thread as answered. (for janitoring).