# What does "class loading deadlock" mean here?

Tags: java, android

I have this classes:

```
public class User {

    public static final NonRegisteredUser NON_REG_USER = new NonRegisteredUser();

    //...

    public static class NonRegisteredUser extends User {
        //...
    }

}
```

And code inspector is detecting this warning:

> Referencing subclass NonRegisteredUser from superclass User
>   initializer might lead to class loading deadlock

What does it mean exactly?

Comment: I think it is pretty clear what it says. You initialize a `NonRegisteredUser` in the `User` class. Every time you load the `User` class, since the `NON_REG_USER` is static it will lead to an eternal loop cause the `NonRegisteredUser` extends the `User` and so on..

Comment: And so on and so on, and depending on implementation of JVM it may not initialize at all.

Comment: It wasn't so clear after all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The deadlock can only occur if you have 2 threads and one starts to load `User` and one starts to load `NonRegisteredUser`. There are synchronizations in place that will cause a deadlock, but then it requires separate threads. If the loading happens in a single thread, there is no deadlock as the thread owns both locks.

Hence the *might* in the message. However deadlocks usually do tend to require a specific environment, so there's nothing weird about that.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on Android, so better I'm gonna solve the warning, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Class loader begins loading `User`.

Static members are init first, [in order of appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133552/explanation-of-how-classloader-loads-static-variables). So the class loader sees the `NonRegisteredUser` class, and tries loading the `User` class for its initialization.

Next, class loader begins loading `User`.

Static members are init first, [in order of appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133552/explanation-of-how-classloader-loads-static-variables). So the class loader sees the `NonRegisteredUser` class, and tries loading the `User` class for its initialization.

Next, class loader begins loading `User`.

Static members are init first, [in order of appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133552/explanation-of-how-classloader-loads-static-variables). So the class loader sees the `NonRegisteredUser` class, and tries loading the `User` class for its initialization...

Comment: Thank you. So, why is that code working? Does it make sense?

Comment: It's probably working because what I just said is not 100% correct. The compiler build a single init process for the class, so the JVM won't blindely iterates over it over and over during runtime. There is probably some optimization in play here, that fixes this kind of issues.

Comment: @Héctor That's a nice question, what happens when you try to use the `User.NON_REG_USER ` attribute or initialize the `User.NonRegisteredUser ` class ?

Comment: @giannischristofakis It works fine. But I'm working on android with several threads, the error may occur so I'm gonna decouple the classes